# How to convert row into column in mui datagrid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I have created datagrid but I want to display single data at a time also in vertical orientation format instead of row.
[This is what I want my grid to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzqBX.png)

[Here is the image of what I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldtnp.png)

Comment: Do you have any image or mockup that can display what you want to look like and the codes do you have now?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it's currently possible, but there is an [open issue](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/3285) from 2021 that you can upvote to try to convince MUI to put it on their development roadmap.